# Scanning WiFi Signals as regular user

Tags: raspbian, linux, debian, root, raspbian-buster

As per this: https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwlist I understand that scanning of WiFi Networks requires root access. If you are a regular user than you can only see the Wifi Network you are connected with. Lets go into my problem...

As a regular user when I use this command in terminal:

```
iwlist wlan0 scan|grep "Frequency\|Quality\|ESSID"
```

Then my output is this:

```
Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
ESSID:"My-WiFi"
```

That is the network I am currently connected to (**My-WiFi**)

When I run this command in terminal as sudo:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan|grep "Frequency\|Quality\|ESSID"
```

Then my output is this:

```
Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
ESSID:"My-WiFi"
Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
Quality=43/70  Signal level=-67 dBm  
ESSID:"MySpectrumWiFi54-2G"
Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
ESSID:"MySpectrumWiFif4-2G"
Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm  
ESSID:"MyCharterWiFieb-2G
```

My problem is that I need to scan the WiFi networks without a normal user having sudo access.

How can I change permissions to run **iwlist wlan0 scan|grep "Frequency\|Quality\|ESSID"** to show the sudo output, but without using sudo or having root access?

Comment: Go it working. The test user is **bob** so I used the command **sudo visudo** and at the end of the file I put in this line **bob ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/iwlist** Now when I am on the user bob I can use **sudo iwlist wlan0 scan|grep "Frequency\|Quality\|ESSID"** without the system asking me for password. Other sudo commands are still protected.

Comment: If you solved it, then enter your answer as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "solution" is the sledgehammer approach.

Editing the sudoers file is not recommended. If you really want to do so it is safer to make a new entry in `/etc/sudoers.d` (which is used to give user `pi` passwordless sudo)

If you want all users to be able to run a command setting `suid` permission is more normal.

```
sudo chmod a+s /sbin/iwlist
```

Comment: This is the correct answer because unlike /etc/sudoers (file that opens with **sudo visudo** command), the contents of /etc/sudoers.d survives system upgrades, so it's preferable to create a file there than to modify /etc/sudoers.